# Ruby on Rails - What does - Routing Error: uninitialized constant ActionController::Responder - mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following error appearing on my Ruby on Rails site:

```
Routing Error: uninitialized constant ActionController::Responder

lib/application_responder.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Below the error its showing a table of Routes matching in priority from top to bottom.

Its appearing on all pages and I'm not sure what the problem is, how can I fix it? * I'm new to Rails.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Update: not sure if its to do with my jobs_controller.rb file, code for it is:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @jobs = Job.page(params[:page]).per(20).order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def new
      @job = Job.new
  end

  def show
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
     @job = Job.new(params.require(:job).permit(:human_sum, :position, :company, :salary, :companywebsite, :contract, :city, :expirydate, :jobtype, :description, :apply, :contactname, :contactemail, :contactphone, ))
      if @job.save
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render "new"
      end
   end
end
```

lib/application_responder.rb -

```
class ApplicationResponder < ActionController::Responder
  include Responders::FlashResponder
  include Responders::HttpCacheResponder

  # Redirects resources to the collection path (index action) instead
  # of the resource path (show action) for POST/PUT/DELETE requests.
  # include Responders::CollectionResponder
end
```

Comment: `lib/application_responder.rb` what is this file about?

Comment: Updated my question with code from application_responder.rb.

Comment: In rails 4.2, you might need the `responders` gem, as this functionality has been extracted out of the core framework.

Comment: So I put gem "responders" in my Gemfile and run bundle install in terminal. Still giving me the same error?

Answer (score 1):

Did a little digging on other articles and found that if I ran...

```
sudo gem install responders
```

It removed the error and my site is back to how it was.